# How to create any array of different generics?

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics

I'd like to create and array of array where types have to be the same. Eg.

```
// Implements the type
[['foo', 'bar'], [null, null], [1, 2]]

// Doesn't implement the type
[[1, 'foo'], [true, undefined]]
```

How could this be done in TypeScript?

Comment: Do you want to specify the types allowed? E.g., the first allows `string`, `null`, or `1`. Or do you want it to be **anything** as long as both elements in each element array?

Comment: I don't want to specify the types in any way

Comment: That's too bad. You can do it with [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) ([like this](https://tsplay.dev/Na0ZPw)) but `any` isn't distributive. I suspect if you want to do it without specifying any types, you'll have to use a do-nothing function so TypeScript can infer the types for you, and I have no idea how you'd write the types for that function. :-|